# Change randomly image in render() without changing it for all other images

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/A-simple-game)  for building a simple game in `LibGDX`.  the basic idea of the game is: there are drops that falls down and the player should couch them by dragging a bucket to the place where the drops getting down.

In the original version all the drops are created from one image of drop  and, what I try to do is to make a rain of different drops (different images of drop), so I created a `List` - `someDrops` of different `Texture` and in the `render()` I replaced:

```
     batch.draw(dropImage, raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
```

with:

```
       int random = MathUtils.random(0, 3;
       batch.draw(someDrops.get(random), raindrop.x, raindrop.y);
```

What I getting is a rain of different drops but they don't get down each with different images but they fall down and all together changing image at the same time.

How can I set so each drop would be with a randomly image from `someDrops` as it falls down with randomly x,y positions.
also I want to add to each drop different points, where should I save it and what type of collection to choose?

```
public class Drop implements ApplicationListener {
   private Texture dropImage;
   private Texture bucketImage;
   private Sound dropSound;
   private Music rainMusic;
   private SpriteBatch batch;
   private OrthographicCamera camera;
   private Rectangle bucket;
   private Array<Rectangle> raindrops;
   private long lastDropTime;
   private List<Texture> someDrops;

   private Texture drop0;   
   private Texture drop1;
   private Texture drop2;
   private Texture drop3;

   @Override
   public void create() {
      // load the images for the droplet and the bucket, 64x64 pixels each
      dropImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet.png"));

      drop0 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet0.png"));
      drop1 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet1.png"));
      drop2 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet2.png"));
      drop3 = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("droplet3.png"));
      bucketImage = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bucket.png"));

      someDrops = new ArrayList<Texture>();

            someDrops.add(new Texture(drop0));
            someDrops.add(new Texture(drop1));
            someDrops.add(new Texture(drop2));
            someDrops.add(new Texture(drop3));

      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480);
      batch = new SpriteBatch();

      // create a Rectangle to logically represent the bucket
      bucket = new Rectangle();
      bucket.x = 800 / 2 - 64 / 2; // center the bucket horizontally
      bucket.y = 20; // bottom left corner of the bucket is 20 pixels above the bottom screen edge
      bucket.width = 64;
      bucket.height = 64;

      //raindrops array and spawn the first raindrop
      raindrops = new Array<Rectangle>();
      spawnRaindrop();

   private void spawnRaindrop() {
      Rectangle raindrop = new Rectangle();
      raindrop.x = MathUtils.random(0, 800-64);
      raindrop.y = 480;
      raindrop.width = 64;
      raindrop.height = 64;
      raindrops.add(raindrop);
      lastDropTime = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
   }

   @Override
   public void render() {
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      camera.update();
      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

      // begin a new batch and draw the bucket and
      // all drops
      batch.begin();
      batch.draw(bucketImage, bucket.x, bucket.y);
      for(Rectangle raindrop: raindrops) {
         //batch.draw(dropImage, raindrop.x, raindrop.y); 
           int random = MathUtils.random(0, 4);
           batch.draw(someDrops.get(random), raindrop.x, raindrop.y); 

      }
      batch.end();

      // check if we need to create a new raindrop
      if(TimeUtils.nanoTime() - lastDropTime > 1000000000) spawnRaindrop();

      Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
      while(iter.hasNext()) {
         Rectangle raindrop = iter.next();
         raindrop.y -= 200 * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
         if(raindrop.y + 64 < 0) iter.remove();
         if(raindrop.overlaps(bucket)) {
            dropSound.play();
            iter.remove();
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `render()` function which i believe you call every frame, you draw all the existing drops, create a new drop if necessary and decrement the y position of the drops.
The problem arises because each time you want to draw even the existing drops, you use

```
int random = MathUtils.random(0, 4);
```

which could give you an image different from the previous draw i.e. when it was at a higher y position. So as it falls down (decrementing y), the image keeps changing every time the render happens until it is finally removed when it falls into the bucket.

To fix this, get a random image only the first time a new drop is being rendered, later save this image and draw it with the same image for the entire lifetime of the drop. The size of this new array to save the corresponding images would remain same as the raindrop array unless a new raindrop has been added in which case you get a new random image.

I will add some code to illustrate the point but i have never programmed in Java or used libgdx so you will have to fix this for compiler errors :)

In the beginning create raindropTextures

```
   private Array<Texture> raindropTextures; // need an ArrayList here?
```

Within create() add this -

```
   raindropTextures = new Array<Texture>();
```

Then within render()

```
   // if the sizes aren't equal, a new raindrop must have been added!!
   if(raindrops.size() != raindropTextures.size())  {
     int random = MathUtils.random(0, 4);
     raindropTextures.add(someDrops.get(random));
   }        
   for(Rectangle raindrop: raindrops, Texture texture: raindropTextures) {
        // make sure the textures and raindrops correspond here; theoritically they should
        batch.draw(texture, raindrop.x, raindrop.y); 
   }
```

And finally -

```
   Iterator<Rectangle> iter = raindrops.iterator();
   Iterator<Texture> iter2 = raindropTextures.iterator();
   //later
   iter.remove()
   iter2.remove()
```

Comment: I understand that the render() draws all the drops in the screen, follow my code how can I draw every time a new image for every drop for the entire lifetime of the drop, could you show it with a code?

Comment: I am not entirely familiar with the available options in libgdx but pseudocode would be- Create an array of textures in create(), check if size of raindrop array and texture array is same in render(), if not add one extra texture to the texture array using somedrops.get(random), and then loop for both array of textures and array of raindrops. Is this explanation better?

Comment: Also be sure to decrement your texture array every time you remove an element from the raindrop array in render()

Comment: I understand the idea my problem is that the `render()` called every frame,when I'm using  `batch.draw(someDrops.get(random), raindrop.x, raindrop.y);` I have an option to control the x,y position but but the image stays the same

Comment: I added some code to the original answer. I don't think it is entirely right, but i hope you get the idea :)